# Can i trigger click on window.printer page in javascript'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to trigger click on save button, on the page that comes right after window.print();

Is it possible? if yes, then please help.

Answer (score 0):

`window.print()` opens the Print dialog box.

Mine has no Save button anywhere on it, and there is no way to interact with something that doesn't exist at all.

That said, browsers do not provide *any* mechanism for JavaScript to interact with any part of the Print dialog box at all.